# Export xlsx files from table as seperated filtered column

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, export, openxlsx

I have a dataset df

```
aa1  bb1  ccc
aa2  bb2  ccc
aa3  bb3  ddd
aa4  bb4  ddd
aa5  bb5  eee
```

I want to export as xlsx files each of them seperated filtered column

```
write.xlsx(df, 'files(ccc,ddd,eee,...).xlsx')
```

output of ccc.xlsx

```
aa1  bb1  ccc
aa2  bb2  ccc
```

output of ddd.xlsx

```
aa3  bb3  ddd
aa4  bb4  ddd
```

output of eee.xls

```
aa5  bb5  eee
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
files <- unique(df$V3) # Or manually files <- c("ccc", "ddd", "eee")
for (f in files) {
  write.xlsx(df[df$V3 == f, ], paste0(f, ".xlsx"))
}
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("aa1", "aa2", "aa3", "aa4", "aa5"), 
  V2 = c("bb1", "bb2", "bb3", "bb4", "bb5"), 
  V3 = c("ccc", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd", "eee")
)
```

Comment: Maybe `files <-  unique(df$V3)` makes it more generic.

Comment: Thanks @maydin, I added that in.